# How to both execute group level and fill when querying data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I currently use Version 0.13.3 of Apache IoTDB. When I query data, I want to use group level to show the query data results, and also I want to fill the empty data points. How to write the query command to achieve the data display that I need?

how to deal this question,someone help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 0.13.X of Apache IoTDB cannot execute `group by level` and `fill` in query command. You  can try to upgrade to Version 1.0.0 or 1.1.0.which will be able to execute this combination